# font-face not showing up on Firefox

Tags: css, font-face

My @font-face works in every other browser I've tried, but on Firefox on Windows, it loads the font resources, but displays the fallback. Here is the code in question:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'VanillaRegular';
    src: url('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19510731/ttfonts/Vanilla-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19510731/ttfonts/Vanilla-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19510731/ttfonts/Vanilla-webfont.woff'),
         url('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19510731/ttfonts/Vanilla-webfont.ttf'),
         url('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19510731/ttfonts/Vanilla-webfont.svg#VanillaRegular');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Then I've embedded it like this:

```
.post h3 {
border-bottom:1px solid #c7e7fa;
color:#51514E;
font-size:22px;
font-weight:bold;
line-height:1.4em;
margin:0.25em 0 8px;
padding:0 0 4px;
font-family: "VanillaRegular", Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Is there something that I specifically need to do for Firefox, or is just my code?

EDIT: Should add, using Firefox 8, and the final product is on Blogger.

Comment: What happens if you place the `ttf` font at the very end? And do you need all the other fallbacks?

Comment: Placing ttf at the end doesn't help, and all the other fallbacks are preferred, since a lot of people on older Internet Explorer versions will be visiting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put those fonts on your own server and they will work. Firefox cannot outsource fonts.

Comment: That's the weird part! It works on the little demo page, but not when I embed it on a site. (this is on blogger by the way)

Comment: Ahhh, that makes sense. Unfortunately, Blogger doesn't let you host files. (wasn't my choice for the host... Blogger is annoying sometimes!) Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Have a look at Google Webfonts, never used them personally but heard it was good.

Comment: Yeah, I would use them, but have to use the specific font Vanilla. Google doesn't have it, unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

I beleive it is because you have

```
@font-face {

... Snip

font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

and your css you have

```
.post h3 {
... snip

font-weight:bold;

... snip
}
```

Unless you have more code there you need another declaration for your bold font.

Check out [css3.info](http://www.css3.info/preview/web-fonts-with-font-face/)'s article.

Comment: That makes total sense, and I tried it, but to no avail. Still showing the fallback font.

Comment: @space wait ... I should have asked first: what version are you using?

Comment: @space ... I forgot, Firefox enforces the same origin rule for fonts... http://webfonts.info/wiki/index.php?title=%40font-face_support_in_Firefox

Comment: Yeah, darn! Ah, well, maybe sometime I'll find a way around it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @space can you not use the `data:` scheme? http://nimbupani.com/using-data-uris-in-css.html

Comment: Wow! I completely forgot about that. It works! Thanks so much.