# how to add font icon to accordion - zurb foundation

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, font-awesome

I'm using Zurb Foundation, working on an accordion. The Zurb accordion comes with a CSS triangle that acts as a toggler, but **I want to use two font-awesome icons instead, depending on whether the li has an active class or not**. Right now I'm getting a placeholder for the icon image.

Would prefer to do this with CSS only, if possible.

Here's my **CSS**:

```
    ul.accordion > li > div.title:after { content:"\f067"; display: block; width: 0; 
height: 0; position: absolute; right: 20px; top: 8px;}

    ul.accordion > li.active .title:after { content:"\f068"; display: block; width: 0; 
height: 0; }
```

Here's the **HTML**:

```
<ul class="accordion">
  <li class="active">
    <div class="title">
      <h5>Accordion Panel 1</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </li>

 <li>
    <div class="title">
      <h5>Accordion Panel 1</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS shown does not specify the `font-family: FontAwesome;`.  Try adding that.

Looks like it's not a permission issue but in case others come along I am leaving the links.

For localhost changing permissions on the font itself could help: [Icon font (@font-face) not rendering on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886817/icon-font-font-face-not-rendering-on-localhost)

Or possible cross domain issues with Firefox: http://www.red-team-design.com/firefox-doesnt-allow-cross-domain-fonts-by-default

Comment: The font awesome icons are showing up everywhere else, so it's most likely not a permission issue.

Comment: Ahh.  I dont know how your CSS would know to use the icon font.  Try adding font-family: FontAwesome; to the CSS?

Comment: dds1024: could be, will give it a try.

Comment: You know, it really was that simple. I should've realized that the font-family was specified in the FontAwesome CSS file only, and not in my main CSS. Accepted and upvoted!